# looping through a C# collections

Tags: c#, collections

i have a class and method

```
public class Datas
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
 public void Funnel()
    {
        string commandText = "select sc.stagename, count(cs.stages_id) as StageCount from currentstage cs inner join stagesconfig sc on cs.stages_id = sc.stages_id group by cs.stages_id,sc.stagename";


        string constrings = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data"].ToString();

        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(constrings);
        SqlCommand myComm = new SqlCommand(commandText, myConn);

        myConn.Open();
        List<Datas> fruitinfo = new List<Datas>();

        SqlDataReader reader = myComm.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                fruitinfo.Add(new Datas
                {
                    Name = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(),
                    Value = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(1))
                });

            }

        }
```

how do you loop through fruitinfo list saving it in form of an array.the array must be similar to this form.intended to replace the items in Data parenthesis with fruitinfo looped list

```
    Data = new Data(new object[]
                {
                    new object[] { "Website visits", 10000 },
                    new object[] { "Downloads", 5000 },
                    new object[] { "Requested price list", 2000 },
                    new object[] { "Invoice sent", 1000 },
                    new object[] { "Finalized", 500 }
                }),
```

Comment: Why do you need this ugly `object[]` at all?

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArray = fruitinfo.Select(x => new object[] { x.Name, x.Value }).ToArray();
```

And the use it with your `Data`-object.

```
Data = new Data(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = fruitinfo.Select(d => new object[] { d.Name, d.Value }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure why you need to produce an array of anonymous objects, but you can use a dictionary.

```
private static void Funnel()
    {
        var datas = new List<Datas>
                        {
                            new Datas { Name = "Website visits", Value = 10000 },
                            new Datas { Name = "Downloads", Value = 5000 },
                            new Datas { Name = "Requested price list", Value = 2000 },
                            new Datas { Name = "Invoice sent", Value = 1000 },
                            new Datas { Name = "Finalized", Value = 500 }
                        };

        var data = datas.ToDictionary(datas1 => datas1.Name, datas1 => datas1.Value);
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}",item.Key, item.Value));
        }

        var arry = data.ToArray();
        foreach (var item in arry)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", item.Key, item.Value));
        }
    }
```

[image: Output]